# Change a Cue start time in Popcorn.js?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, popcornjs

I need to change a Cue point in a video using Popcorn.js.
Is there a way to edit the time of a Cue event already sent to he Popcorn player via the Cue() method?

Thanks!

Comment: Turns out you can't, but they might add the function in the furture. the way to do it to delete the cue, and add a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var events = Popcorn.getTrackEvents();
for (var e in events) {
  Popcorn.removeTrackEvent(events[e]._id);
}
Popcorn.cue(newTime, newFunction);
```

Its not exactly the editing the event, but it works fine for me - i need to replace everything and then play video again.

There are also getTrackEvent(obj, id) and getLastTrackEventId(obj) - you can handle each event separately (i did not tested it).

It looks it will be implemented in [new release 1.3](https://webmademovies.lighthouseapp.com/projects/63272/tickets/1084-modify-cue-after-its-been-set)